# Bootstrap validator for select box using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, bootstrapvalidator

I am trying to validate select box using ajax in codeigniter.
I also tried revalidated with bootstrap validator but due to adding revalidated the whole validation is not working.
Thats why I remove revalidated function.
Now I use disabled. It now shows red line error its good. When I select subcategory then it should change in green color but it still show red color error.

> Here is screen shot of problem

[image]

and second picture:

> In this picture a real problem is shown

[image]

Here is my code of view file:

```
       <form class="form-horizontal" id="form_professional" role="form" method="Post" action=""> 
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
       <label for="select" class="control-label col-sm-4">Select Subcategory</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">   
      <select class="subcategory1" id="select" name="framework[]" multiple class="form-control">
      </select>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

I am getting data through ajax according to related category.Every thing working fine.But the problem is that when i click on submit button it show red color error on subcategory field because i used excluded = 'disable'.
After the selecting multiple subcategory it still show red line error.It does not change in green line.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.subcategory1').multiselect({
  nonSelectedText: 'Select Subcategory',
  enableFiltering: true,
  enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
  buttonWidth:'300px'
 });
});


    $('#form_professional').bootstrapValidator({
        // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
         excluded: ':disabled',
        fields: {
          professional_building:{
            validators: {
                regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\s]+$/,
                        message: 'The building name can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                    }
            }
          },
            'framework[]': {
                validators: {
                   notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please specify at least one browser you use daily for development'
                    }

                }
            }
});
```

Comment: which version of formvalidation are u using - because afaik bootstrapvalidator is deprecated ?

Comment: Please help how i solve this problem